# Making phone call in j2me and getting status of that call

Tags: java-me, lwuit

I am developing a project where I need to initiate a phone call to the given no. If the contact doesn't receives the call I need to initiate another call for another user. So, how can I achieve this in J2me. Here I am using Lwuit's Display.getInstance().execute("tel:"+) method to initiate a call.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do anything other than initiate a call to the number at which point your application loses control of the phone. E.g. in [Codename One](http://www.codenameone.com/) we have `Display.getInstance().dial(phone)` in LWUIT you will need to use `Display.getInstance().execute("tel://" + phone);`.

Comment: Yes those are the methods I have used to initiate calls but on E-71 it pops up a dialog asking yes or no. That happened while call control permissions to the midlet are set to always allowed. In project this has to be a direct calling as a spy call without notifying user.

Comment: That's a virus so it isn't allowed by the security features of J2ME.